# JPA entity containing a class from an external jar

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I'm building a Roo webapp using JPA and Hibernate.  I have a library project that is referenced from the webapp.  The Roo webapp has the following entity:

```
@RooJpaEntity
@RooJavaBean
public class UpdatePolicyHolder {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Policy.class)
    private List<Policy> policies;
    private String deviceId;
    private long timestamp;

}
```

The `Policy` class is defined in an external library, included as a jar file.  When starting the application, Hibernate complains that it cannot determine the type of `Policy`:

```
Could not determine type for: com.company.policy.Policy, at table:...
```

I can't seem to find anything online about issues around included external classes.  I haven't made any changes to the standard, Roo-generated persistence.xml file.  I did modify the applicationContext.xml file to make sure the package for both the entity and the `Policy` class are covered by the component scan element.

The webapp project is packaged as a war and is currently run via a `mvn jetty:run` command.  The jar containing `Policy` is included via a Maven dependency.

Comment: Describe your packaging. Is your app an `ear` or a `war`? Where's the jar with `Policy` and were's the `jar` with `persistence.xml`?

Comment: @rzymek My edits above should address your question

Comment: Show me the `Policy` class, please.

Answer (score 0):

The jar containing Policy must contain the `META-INF/persistence.xml` to let 3rd party apps to scan the entities inside that jar.

Then set Spring `EntityManagerFactory` for scanning persistent entities:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" 
      value="UNIT_NAME_OF_POLICY_PERSISTENCE_XML"/>
  <property name="dataSource" ref="..."/>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company.policy" />
...
</bean>
```

Regards

Comment: So why this does not apply to xml-mapped entities?

Comment: This issue shouldn't affect xml-mapped entities